# Find physical path to public certificate in Windows Server 2003 LocalMachine/My store

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I am trying to find the file system path to a public key that was imported into the LocalMachine/My (personal) cert store so that I can grant read & execute permissions to a custom App_pool account. I tried using `findprivatekey.exe` and `winhttpcertcfg.exe` with no luck.  Here is the path I have so far, just don't know which one to apply the permissions to.

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

`findprivatekey.exe` always fails to locate the cert.

`winhttpcertcfg -l -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s MyCertificate`  returns with

> Access was not successfully obtained for the private key.  this can only be done by the user who installed the certificate.

However, I installed the cert so I think it has to do with the fact its not a private cert but a public one.

Any advice...?  Also, this is on Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have learned with this issue, when you import the .cer file on a Windows Server 2003 box, a pop-up (screenshot below) window will ask about validation. Click YES or you will have the access to the private key issue.

Security Warning Screenshot:

[image]

That was one thing I have noticed because I had one server out of three that the pop-up showed and I had no issues assigning permissions to NETWORKSERVICE and ASPNET.

A workaround is to export the cert from another server with the key creating a password. I was able to do this in IIS 7 on the server that the certificate was created for. Once I had the .pfx, I imported on the other two servers that had this issue and I was able to assign the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The Certificates are usually imported into a registry location
e.g.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
   Software
      Microsoft
         SystemCertificates
```

See [System Store Locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/system-store-locations)

If you are looking for what an application does, then download [Microsoft ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), which will allow you to monitor what files and registry locations are touched on a system for an operation.